# PostgreSQL casting "2022-06-22T02:22:11.310682187Z" to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, parsing, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to convert a timestamp string to a timestamp which is in the ISO8601 format (-isch) in a PostgreSQL DB. Although I am almost there, it's just not what it should be.

The string is as follows:

2022-06-22T02:22:11.310682187Z

Using various sources on to_timestamp, I was able to run the following command:

to_timestamp(timestampstring,'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.MSUS"Z"')

Which gave me the following result:

2022-06-22 02:22:11.992 +0200

Which is almost what it should be, where it not for the fact that it has added a +2 timezone where the string is in UTC and the milli/micro seconds are not what the should be.

Some things that I should mention, I know that the string is a bit odd (there is no need for that precision in the seconds), but this is what I get from the API I'm calling (which is not my own). I've tried using a format with only the milli of micro seconds but to_timestamp will throw an error in that situation. I've tried to indicate that the Z is actually the UTC timezone, but to no avail. Also, I realise that I can also parse this by taking a substring of the time but giving that the format is a known format, that feels a bit like giving up. Any help on how I could get this to parse properly.

Comment: would you try `"date_column"::timestamp` ?

Comment: ..... o.o ...this actually works. I thought that I tried this, but given that it works it most certainly did someting different. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
SELECT '2022-06-22T02:22:11.310682187Z'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC';
```

Result: 2022-06-22 02:22:11.310682

Comment: This indeed works, I thought I had tried this before ... but apparently I messed some part up as I did not get it to work. Out of curiousity, the Z indicates the UTC timezone, but it's not picked up it seems?

Comment: I'm always confused when working with time zones, but this is what the manual says: All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.